# "An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property" with toolstripstatus

Tags: c#, timer, toolstripstatuslabel

I get the error written in the title using toolstripstatus in the line `serverstatus.Text = "Server Online " + totalTime + " ms";` and `serverstatus.Text = "Server Offline";` every X second the stripstatus (serverstatus) will update the clients if the server is online or not.

```
public static double PingTimeAverage(string host)
    {
        long totalTime = 0;
        int timeout = 120;
        int echoNum = 1; //number of pings
        Ping pingSender = new Ping();

        try
        {
            PingReply reply = pingSender.Send(host, timeout);
            totalTime += reply.RoundtripTime;
            serverstatus.Text = "Server Online " + totalTime + " ms";
        }
        catch
        {
            serverstatus.Text = "Server Offline";
        }

        return totalTime / echoNum;

    }
```

and the timer tick

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        PingTimeAverage("any url/dns");
    }
```

What i should change?

Comment: If you look at the related column on the right you could see that there are at least 5 question with your exact problem. None of them helps you?

Comment: Remove `static`  You aren't doing anything with the return value.

Comment: What is `serverstatus`?  If it's a class type then `Text` isn't static and you need an instance of it.

Comment: you are trying to use an instance field `serverstatus` in a static method.  You can't do that.